# Change user/group for PHP-FPM (Docker)

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, bitnami

I ran docker php-fpm container with the following config

```
  php-fpm:
    tty: true
    image: bitnami/php-fpm:latest
    volumes:
      - ./www:/www
```

php-fpm is running as daemon:daemon. How to **properly** change user/group for the container? For example, run it as www:www...

Answer (score 1):

Build this into your Docker image.  In your Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM bitnami/php-fpm:latest # (Debian-based)

# Create the non-root runtime user.  It does not need a
# specific uid, shell, home directory, or other settings.
RUN adduser --system --no-create-home --group www

# Copy the files in as root, so they don't accidentally get
# overwritten at runtime
# (The base image sets WORKDIR /app)
COPY www ./

# Then set the runtime user
USER www

# The base image provides a useful CMD; leave it as is
```

(Some of the details around the base image's `WORKDIR` and `CMD` come from looking up [the `bitnami/php-fpm` image on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/php-fpm), and in turn following the link to [the image's Dockerfile](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-php-fpm/blob/7.4.13-debian-10-r4/7.4/debian-10/Dockerfile).)

Then your `docker-compose.yml` file just needs to specify the details to use this Dockerfile.  You do not need `volumes:`; the code is already built into the image.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-fpm:
    build: .
    # ports: ['9000:9000']
    # no volumes:
```

In practice it usually doesn't matter much what specific user ID a container process is running as, just so long as it isn't (or, depending on your needs, is) the special `root` user (with user ID 0).  There shouldn't be a difference between the container process running as `daemon` vs. `www`.  Conversely, looking at the `bitnami/php-fpm` Dockerfile, it isn't obvious to me that anything would cause the container to *not* run as root.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a Dockerfile, I have created a common.conf file:

```
user=www-data
group=www-data
listen.owner=www-data
listen.group=www-data
```

in docker-compose.yml:

```
php:
  image: bitnami/php-fpm:8.0 # or any other
  ...
  volumes:
    # path to common.conf may differ if using a different image
    - ./path-to/common.conf:/opt/bitnami/php/etc/common.conf:ro
```

To check the user, I have a index.php:

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
```